# Distribution of negative of standard normal variate

Tags: normal-distribution, self-learning

Let  $X$ be a  standard normal variate. Consider another variate $Y$ such that

$$Y = \begin{cases}
-X & \text{for $-2 < X< 2$} \\
X & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$

I need to check whether $(X,Y)$ follow bivariate normal and correlation between $X$ and $Y$ is $1$.

My attempt: Since negative of a normal random variable is also normal, $Y$ is identical to $X$ and therefore their correlation is $1$. Since marginal are normal variates, $(X,Y)$ follow bivariate normal.

Am I right?

Comment: For a similar exercise, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent#An_asymmetric_example. It is true that $Y$ is also standard normal, but that does not imply $(X,Y)$ is bivariate normal (as the answer below argues). And the correlation cannot be exactly $1$ because $X$ and $Y$ are not linearly related.

Answer (score 1):

$X$ and $Y$ are not bivariate normal. If they were, then $X+Y$ would have be normal (or degenerate). But $X+Y=0$ on a set of positive probability (namley $\{|X| <2\}$) and it is not the zero random variable. 
Covariance can be computed explicitly using normal density. $X=EY=0$ so you only have to compute $EXY=-EX^{2}I_{\{|X| <2\}} +EX^{2}I_{\{|X| >2\}}$. I leave this to you.